# WordPress register_sidebars woes

Tags: php, wordpress

#### The Issue:

```
$footer_widgets = array(
    'name'          => sprintf(__('Sidebar %d'), $i ),
    'id'            => "sidebar-$i",
    'description'   => '',
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>'
);

register_sidebars(4, $footer_widgets);
```

Is producing the image below and I'm not sure why. When I copy and paste the code from the [register_sidebars codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars) it **still** does not work properly.

[image: Widgets]

#### What Works:

When I remove `$footer_widgets["name"]` it all of a sudden works again. I can't seem to change the name to suit my needs so I can actually continue building my theme.

My apologies if this is a repeat. I did take the time to scour stackoverflow and other search engines and did not find anything that could help me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hey, the code you pasted won't generate that menu -- the menu says "Footer" and the code you pasted looks like it came directly from the codex.  What code are you actually using?  And am I correct in assuming that the problem is the four zeros appended to the sidebar names instead of a 2,3, and 4?

Comment: That is correct and I am pasting the exact code from the codex because nothing else I did actually worked. You are also correct about the four zeros instead of numbers that increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a peculiar note in the [parameters section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars#Parameters) that says:

> Note: If copying from default usage above, remove `sprintf( )` wrapper
>   function.

working code:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'so16969325_widgets_init' );
function so16969325_widgets_init()
{
    $footer_widgets = array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar %d', 'txt_domain' ),
        'id'            => "sidebar-$i",
        'description'   => '',
        'class'         => '',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    );
    register_sidebars( 4, $footer_widgets );
}
```